# Unshort link generated by android app with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to unshort an url generated by Banggood android app. The link is

```
https://banggood.app.link/ifPZZ5jS98
```

The code works great with all bit.ly urls. But with this url it doesn't work. Any idea.

My code:

```
import requests
import warnings
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning


def unshort_link(url):
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore',InsecureRequestWarning)
    session = requests.Session()
    resp = session.head(url, allow_redirects=True, verify=False)
    unshort_url = resp.url
    return unshort_url


unshorted_url = unshort_link("https://banggood.app.link/ifPZZ5jS98")

print(unshorted_url)

# expected result: https://www.banggood.com/LANGFEITE-L8S-2019-Version-15Ah-48_1V-800W+2-Dual-Motor-Folding-Electric-Scooter-Color-Display-DC-Brushless-Motor-45km-or-h-Top-Speed-40km-Range-EU-Plug-p-1486764.html?akmClientCountry=IT&channel=googleshopping&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgs&utm_campaign=xibei-ssc-it-all-0303_prdshare_copy&utm_content=xibei&_branch_match_id=762227340915062987
```

Comment: Looked into it, looks like the website is protected by CloudFront and it's blocking your code from working properly.

Comment: @tayler6000 any idea how to bypass this?